# Can I save coockie for page with get method

Tags: php, get

I want save cookie for one page but I want this will save only for specific page,
page one: http....page?id=1;
page two: http...page?id=2;

I want different cookie for all one, and when I will save for the first the cookie isn't save for the second.
sorry about my English.... and thanks you..

Comment: $_COOKIE[md5($page_url)] = serialise(you cookies key value);

Answer (score 0):

The fourth parameter of set_cookie lets you provide a path. You could set this path using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

```
setcookie('foo', 'bar', null, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

setcookie docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: But it's save for 'http...page?id=1'  and 'http...page?id=2' but I want it will save only for one...

Comment: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` would give you the `id=1` bit. You could then use that value to either store as the variable name or value.